# How to fade image to image in a jQuery slideshow

Tags: jquery, html

So below I currently have an image slideshow implementing some jQuery code. The problem I am having is I want each image to fade in and out as I click on the little square. Note that if anyone has a better way to write the code for the slideshow in general feel free to mess around with it :D. Thanks in advance!

```
<header>
    <ul>
        <li id="image1"></li>
        <li id="image2"></li>
        <li id="image3"></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/justinw001/bygMb/6/**

Comment: You can use the jQuery fade out/in more easily if you put the images in three separate "div" tags (you can even keep them as background images). Then hide and show those divs by id or class: $("div-id").fadeIn(500)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple transition will do:

```
transition: background-image 1s;
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyWorker/bygMb/7/

Comment: Thank you for the tip! Wish I would have known that earlier.